# Replace values in a dataframe based on dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dataset with a few columns including indicator code & indicator Name.

[image]

I want to change the indicator name based on the indicator code. I have a dict where the indicator code is the key, and the name is the value. Any ideas how to do this?

```
tempdict = {'EN.ATM.GHGT.KT.CE': 'Total',
            'EN.ATM.CO2E.KT': 'CO2',
            'EN.ATM.METH.KT.CE': 'CH4',
           'EN.ATM.NOXE.KT.CE': 'N2O',
           'EN.ATM.GHGO.KT.CE': 'Other',
           'EN.ATM.PM25.MC.M3': 'PM2.5',
           'EN.ATM.PM25.MC.ZS': 'PM2.5_WHO'}
```

The dataset looks like this. It is named DF

Comment: show us the dataset also

Comment: i just did add it always sunny

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use the map function like this:

```
   df=pd.DataFrame(['EN.ATM.GHGT.KT.CE','EN.ATM.GHGT.KT.CE','EN.ATM.CO2E.KT'],columns= 
       ['col'])
   df['col'].map(tempdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have indicator code & indicator Name as column "IndicatorCode" and "IndicatorName" and your dataframe as df. And also I assume that you already have your indicator code and is waiting to fill your indicator name based on indicator code.

This is what you need

```py
df["IndicatorName"] = df["IndicatorCode"].map(tempdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way using `map()`,

```
df['Indicator Name'].map(tempdict).fillna(df['Indicator Name'])
```